# Building QGIS with vs2019

Tags: qgis, build

I have tried to build qgis from source with this document https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/ltr-3_22/INSTALL.md but I got many errors. Recently I found this guide
https://www.mail-archive.com/qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org/msg52306.html but the build gives me the following error.

```
..\qgis-3.22.13\out\build\x64-Release\qgsrasterhistogramwidget.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QwtPlotCurve::setSamples(class QVector<class QPointF> const &)" (__imp_?setSamples@QwtPlotCurve@@QEAAXAEBV?$QVector@VQPointF@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl QgsRasterHistogramWidget::refreshHistogram(void)" (?refreshHistogram@QgsRasterHistogramWidget@@QEAAXXZ)
..\qgis-3.22.13\out\build\x64-Release\qgscurveeditorwidget.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QwtPlotCurve::setSamples(class QVector<class QPointF> const &)" (__imp_?setSamples@QwtPlotCurve@@QEAAXAEBV?$QVector@VQPointF@@@@@Z)
..\qgis-3.22.13\out\build\x64-Release\qgsgradientcolorrampdialog.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QwtPlotCurve::setSamples(class QVector<class QPointF> const &)" (__imp_?setSamples@QwtPlotCurve@@QEAAXAEBV?$QVector@VQPointF@@@@@Z)
..\qgis-3.22.13\out\build\x64-Release\qgsrasterhistogramwidget.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QwtPlotHistogram::setSamples(class QVector<class QwtIntervalSample> const &)" (__imp_?setSamples@QwtPlotHistogram@@QEAAXAEBV?$QVector@VQwtIntervalSample@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl QgsRasterHistogramWidget::refreshHistogram(void)" (?refreshHistogram@QgsRasterHistogramWidget@@QEAAXXZ)
..\qgis-3.22.13\out\build\x64-Release\qgscurveeditorwidget.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QwtPlotHistogram::setSamples(class QVector<class QwtIntervalSample> const &)" (__imp_?setSamples@QwtPlotHistogram@@QEAAXAEBV?$QVector@VQwtIntervalSample@@@@@Z)
..\qgis-3.22.13\out\build\x64-Release\qgshistogramwidget.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QwtPlotHistogram::setSamples(class QVector<class QwtIntervalSample> const &)" (__imp_?setSamples@QwtPlotHistogram@@QEAAXAEBV?$QVector@VQwtIntervalSample@@@@@Z)
..\qgis-3.22.13\out\build\x64-Release\output\bin\qgis_gui.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Am I missing a package to install?

Is there any updated documentation to make the build successful?